# Dynamically formatting date to a datetime object directly from MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, datetime

I have a MySQL database with a `DATETIME` formatted column, which is populated with the date of the row entry. This data is formatted in my project as `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"`.

I want to convert this date to a datetime object dynamically (from each database entry), but I currently receive the error

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

However, if I use the actual outputted string of the date, it does work:

```
using System.Globalization;

var date = DateTime.ParseExact("11/12/2013 11:13:45 PM", 
                               "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But if I dynamically add the date, it doesn't work:

```
using System.Globalization;

var dt = item.Timestamp;
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, 
                               "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If I were to output the `dt` variable it would display as `"11/13/2013 11:13:21 PM"`.

Can anyone see why my dynamic dates aren't being recognised?

Comment: What is the type of the `Timestamp` property?

Comment: the Timestamp property is the 'DATETIME' column in my database, with the item variable representing each row in my database. cheers!

Comment: but what **type** is `item.Timestamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your problem is the day-month order.
At the end you said the date displays as `"11/13/2013 11:13:21 PM"`.
In this case, you need to parse in this correct order; it errors because there's no month 13.

So, make the format be `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"`.

In other words, you wouldn't have noticed this problem yesterday!